# How to generate README.md in Polymer?

Tags: polymer

The Polymer custom elements (like Iron or Paper elements) have the description for each element in the comments of the HTML file of every element, description which is identical with the README.md file.

So I assume that the README.md is generated by a tool based on those details in the comments.

A tool which I also assume could be added as a gulp process.

Can anyone point how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Polymer CLI. It is a command-line based tool for scaffolding out new elements and projects. More information on how to install and use it can be found [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli)

Comment: The Polymer CLI provides several commands, really helpful in various situations, but none of them do particularly what I asked for. Or maybe it's there and I just don't see it.